# Exclude single OU from user profile sync in Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, userprofile-sync

I am trying to exclude single OU called ServiceAccounts from User profile sync in SharePoint 2016. 
I tried the query below but its not working,

```
(|(isDeleted=TRUE)(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)
(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(!(memberOf=OU=ServiceAccounts,OU=Centers,DC=Contoso,DC=com)))
```

Can some one tell me whats wrong with this? Its not excluding OU members and keep syncing all users. I tried the purge command too after each sync but no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just uncheck the Organization Unit from being synchronized. That said, it is possible that the service accounts will generate a Profile regardless, depending on what they're doing.

Comment: That's what I did first  but did not work for some reason and I started looking in to queries. There is an option to check to exclude disabled accounts but that also does not work and I had to mentioned that in LDAP query as well as you can see. Not sure if its SP 2016 thing, not very friendly with UI ? unchecking OU only is not doing it for me.

Comment: Are all of these SharePoint service accounts; or a better way to ask, are the service accounts you're seeing in the Manage User Profiles only accounts used with SharePoint in some form or fashion?

Comment: no its showing lots more other service accounts as well for example exchange admin is also showing up , when I edit the user profile , "Distinguished Name = CN-Accname,OU=ServiceAccounts,OU=Centers,DC=Contoso,DC=com. so I believe all service accounts are in there , I want to exclude them from sync.

Comment: The proper way to do this would be to deselect the OU from the sync process then purge the service accounts from the UPSA. When using AD Import, accounts are not purged automatically under any circumstances.

Comment: I agree, that's how it should work , but not in this case.

Comment: A quick an easy way to check if any user excluded as result of change is to run getNonImportedObjects and it should show you the users that are marked for deletion. in this case even thou OU is unchecked but showing no users marked for deletion.

Comment: Incase some is having the same issue, After I gave up, I used PS to delete all user profiles from the database , deleted the sync connection, recreated sync connection with different name uncheck the one OU that I don't want to sync and ran a full sync. Sync completed and users from unwanted OU were not synced. Not the best  way to do that because  now I will have to run scripts again to set the values for some of the properties that we are using like time zone and others.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Finally I open up a case with MS and here is solution and some more details. As mentioned by @Trevor , uncheck the OU and it will exclude users, this will work but number of users showing on the Manage Profile Page will not go down. So for example is number of user profiles on top right was 100 , you uncheck the OU , number will still show as 100. it will go up if you add new user in AD after next sync but it will not go down.

This is a known issue with MS and will be resolved in August 2017 CU, as per MS.

Issue occurs when MySiteClean up job runs. Timer Job is responsible to clean up any excluded user profiles or disabled accounts but it’s not doing it. All excluded and disabled users are stored in table called "upa.userprofilescheduledforremoval" this is new in 2016. 
For more details you can check out this link and how to resolve this for the time being.

Hope this will help someone struggling with the same issue.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2017/05/22/sharepoint-2016-mysitecleanup-job-functionality-changes/

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved in August CU released today : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011049/august-8-2017-update-for-sharepoint-server-2016-kb4011049